# Call to undefined function inval()

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have a error in My_Model in CodeIgniter. I've looked everywhere but nothing My_Model:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class MY_Model extends CI_Model
    {
    protected $_table_name = '';
    protected $_primary_key = 'id';
    protected $_primary_filter = 'intval';
    protected $_order_by = '';
    protected $_rules = array();
    protected $_timestamps = FALSE;
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
    }
    public function get($id = NULL, $single = FALSE)
    {
        if ($id != NULL)
        {   
            $filter = $this->_primary_filter;
            $id = $filter($id);
            $this->db->where($this->_primary_key,$id);
            $method = 'row';
        }
        elseif($single == TRUE)
        {
            $method = 'row';
        }
        else
        {
            $method = 'result';
        }   
        if(!count($this->db->ar_orderby))
        {
            $this->db->order_by($this->_order_by);  
        }
        return $this->db->get($this->_table_name)->$method();
    }
    public function get_by($where, $single = FALSE)
    {
        $this->db->where($where);
        return $this->get(NULL, $single);
    }
    public function save($data, $id = NULL)
    {
        //Set timestamp
        if($this->_timestamps == TRUE)
        {
            $now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            $id || $data['created'] = $now;
            $data['modified'] = $now;
        }
        //INSERT
        if ($id ===NULL)
        {
            !isset($data[$this->_primary_key]) || $data[$this->_primary_key] = NULL;
            $this->db->set($data);
            $this->db->insert($this->_table_name);
            $id = $this->db->insert_id();
        }
        //UPDATE
        else
        {
            $filter = $this->_primary_filter;
            $this->db->set($data);
            $this->db->where($this->_primary_key,$id);
            $this->db->update($this->_table_name);
        }
        return $id;
    }
    public function delete($id)
    {
        $filter = $this->_primary_filter;
        $id = $filter($id);
        $this->db->where($this->_primary_key,$id);
        $this->db->limit(1);
        $this->db->delete($this->_table_name);
    }

}
?>
```

And in my Controller I call the function in this way:

```
public function delete()
    {
        $this->page_m->delete(3);
    }
```

When I write:cms/page/delete...the error is:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function inval() in C:\xampp\htdocs\application\core\MY_Model.php on line 75
```

Help me please

Comment: can you tell me plz your save function is working fine ?

Comment: change **`$id = $filter($id);`** to **`$id = intval($id);`** inside **`function delete()`** and try.

Comment: check your 
$filter = $this->_primary_filter;
        $id = $filter($id);
is your id is correct ?

Comment: `protected $_primary_filter = 'intval';` yet the error message contains `inval` (without the t). And the last usage of this function thingy in your code snippet is on line 72 not 75 as stated in the eror message. Are you sure the code you've posted is the one being executed?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in the  **`delete()`** function

```
$filter = $this->_primary_filter;
$id = $filter($id);
```

Make sure you receive the correct **`id`** and **`type`** (int, bool)

Comment: What do you mean by "correct id and type (int, bool)" ? Please post the answers here. You can post your assumption in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Change Your :

```
$filter = $this->_primary_filter;
$id = $filter($id);
```

To :

```
$id = intval($id);
```